# Binding two ListViews in setCellFactory Java8

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have two ListViews, `plantImages` and `allPlants`. `plantImages` has all the images of plants and `allPlants` has plant objects that have all the information about plant. I want to list both of them on a scene so that images of plants are shown in front of their names retrieved from `plantImage` elements. Images and their respective plant objects are in the same order in both lists. The code that I have worked but has a lot of bugs, like when some clicks on the image or name of a plant that cell vanishes and the list is reordered. I need something that can bind both of list together. The code that I have so far is:

The atomic number counts the number of lambda expression runs and is used in the same sense as someone would use iterator `i` in a loop to work with two lists. The problem is that it gets updated on every click event. 
Is there a cleaner way to implement this?

```
       class Employee{
         String name;
         int age;
    }

class controller{
     ListView <ImageView>images = importImages();
     ListView <Employee> employees = importEmployees();
}

AtomicInteger runCount= new AtomicInteger(0);
        employees.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell <Employee>() {
            private ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Employee e, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(e, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText("empty");
                    setGraphic(null);
                }else {
           imageview.setImage(images.get(runCount.get()).getImage());
                setText(employees.get(runCount.get()).toString());
                    setGraphic(imageview);
                    runCount.getAndIncrement();
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Are you assuming the cell’s `updateItem()` methods will be called in order, once for each element in the items list? That definitely is not the case. Doesn’t it work if you just call `getIndex()` to get the correct index? Probably better would just be to create a class that encapsulates both sets of data, and keep a single list.

Comment: @James_D Yes, I'm assuming this and it definitely is not the case. That's the reason why images keep moving. My goal is to show both images and the objects in front of each other.

Comment: @James_D Of course, adding image property in the plant class makes more sense but other team members didn't agree on it. DEMOCRACY

Comment: Make a specific class in addition to the existing classes that contains two final members (one reference to each of the existing classes). Use it only in the context of your list view (you can even make it a private inner class). Then it’s just an implementation detail that doesn’t affect any other part of the code. (If they don’t agree to that, find a new team.)

Comment: `getIndex()` didn't work.

Comment: Other options: override `updateIndex()` instead of `updateItem()`. Or, make a `ListView<Integer>`, so your item is just the index into both lists.

Comment: `class FullPlant { ImageView img, Plant p }` then populate its listview  with objects from both listviews?

Comment: Yes, that’s basically what I had in mind.

Comment: @James_D can't find the `updateIndex()` method anywhere in oracle documentation and can you please elaborate a little about the other option it seems easy to implement

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/IndexedCell.html#updateIndex(int)

Comment: Create a [mre] and post it in your question. (Don't post the actual project, just create something *complete* from scratch that reproduces the same problem.) Then I can provide an actual answer.

Comment: ok, i'll do that

Comment: @James_D updated

Comment: I'm confused by the code (which is nowhere near complete, btw). Do you still want the individual list views displayed, as well as the one where the cell displays the object plus the image? That seems weird.

Comment: At any rate, you should never use a node type (`ImageView`) as the data type for a `ListView`. Use `Image` instead.

Comment: listviews aren't displayed individually, only once combined

Comment: So you don't need them at all (why waste resources on UI elements you have no intention of displaying?). Use `List`s instead.

Comment: I just want image+name in a horizontal box. Tried HBox but there are 300+ images and I wasn't able to add scroll in it. Listview solved that problem but now I'm not able to accurately display them togther

Comment: just trying to get it done, already past deadline, you know how it works, make it to the level where it works and then do the touchups at the end

Comment: No, sorry: this forum is not just for you. I'll post an answer but only if it's an appropriate standard of code that will be useful for all users of the site.

Comment: @James_D thanks, using updateIndex() solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred approach is to create a class encapsulating both the object and its image. This class only needs to be scoped to the controller (or class where the list view is defined, if not using FXML):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<EmployeeWithImage> listView ;

    private List<Employee> employees ;
    private List<Image> images ;

    public Controller() {
        // presumably in real life these are populated elsewhere...
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=40 ; i++) {
            employees.add(new Employee("Employee "+i, 20+i));
            images.add(createImage(i));
        }       
    }

    public void initialize() {



        for (int i = 0 ; i < employees.size(); i++)  {
            Image image = null ;
            if (i < images.size()) {
                image = images.get(i);
            }
            listView.getItems().add(new EmployeeWithImage(employees.get(i), image));
        }

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {

            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

            {
                setPrefHeight(100);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(EmployeeWithImage employee, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(employee, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(employee.getEmployee().getName());
                    imageView.setImage(employee.getImage());
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Image createImage(int i) {
        /// just a hack to get an image with a number in it
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
        label.setMinSize(100, 100);
        label.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        label.requestLayout();
        label.applyCss();
        new Scene(label);
        return label.snapshot(null, null);
    }

    private static class EmployeeWithImage {

        private final Employee employee ;
        private final Image image ;
        public EmployeeWithImage(Employee employee, Image image) {
            super();
            this.employee = employee;
            this.image = image;
        }
        public Employee getEmployee() {
            return employee;
        }
        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to keep the two lists separate, and use the index to hook into the list of images:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Employee> listView ;

    private List<Employee> employees ;
    private List<Image> images ;

    public Controller() {
        // presumably in real life these are populated elsewhere...
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=40 ; i++) {
            employees.add(new Employee("Employee "+i, 20+i));
            images.add(createImage(i));
        }       
    }

    public void initialize() {

        listView.getItems().setAll(employees);

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {

            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

            {
                setPrefHeight(100);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Employee employee, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(employee, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(employee.getName());
                    int index = getIndex();
                    if (index >= 0 && index < images.size()) {
                        imageView.setImage(images.get(index));
                        setGraphic(imageView);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Image createImage(int i) {
        /// just a hack to get an image with a number in it
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
        label.setMinSize(100, 100);
        label.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        label.requestLayout();
        label.applyCss();
        new Scene(label);
        return label.snapshot(null, null);
    }


}
```

Or, still using the objects in the list, you can create a `Map<Employee, Image>` to look up the images:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Employee> listView ;

    private List<Employee> employees ;
    private List<Image> images ;

    private Map<Employee, Image> employeeImageMap ;

    public Controller() {
        // presumably in real life these are populated elsewhere...
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=40 ; i++) {
            employees.add(new Employee("Employee "+i, 20+i));
            images.add(createImage(i));
        }       
    }

    public void initialize() {

        employeeImageMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < Math.min(employees.size(), images.size()); i++) {
            employeeImageMap.put(employees.get(i), images.get(i));
        }

        listView.getItems().setAll(employees);

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {

            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

            {
                setPrefHeight(100);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Employee employee, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(employee, empty);
                if (empty || employee == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(employee.getName());
                    imageView.setImage(employeeImageMap.get(employee));
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Image createImage(int i) {
        /// just a hack to get an image with a number in it
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
        label.setMinSize(100, 100);
        label.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        label.requestLayout();
        label.applyCss();
        new Scene(label);
        return label.snapshot(null, null);
    }


}
```

Another approach is to make a `ListView<Integer>`, populate it with the indexes, and then use the index in `updateItem()`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Integer> listView ;

    private List<Employee> employees ;
    private List<Image> images ;

    public Controller() {
        // presumably in real life these are populated elsewhere...
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=40 ; i++) {
            employees.add(new Employee("Employee "+i, 20+i));
            images.add(createImage(i));
        }       
    }

    public void initialize() {


        for (int i = 0 ; i < employees.size(); i++) {
            listView.getItems().add(i);
        }

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {

            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

            {
                setPrefHeight(100);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Integer index, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(index, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(employees.get(index).getName());
                    if (index >= 0 && index < images.size()) {
                        imageView.setImage(images.get(index));
                        setGraphic(imageView);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Image createImage(int i) {
        /// just a hack to get an image with a number in it
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
        label.setMinSize(100, 100);
        label.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        label.requestLayout();
        label.applyCss();
        new Scene(label);
        return label.snapshot(null, null);
    }


}
```

And one final approach is to populate the list view with the objects, and override the `updateIndex()` method, instead of `updateItem()`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Employee> listView ;

    private List<Employee> employees ;
    private List<Image> images ;

    public Controller() {
        // presumably in real life these are populated elsewhere...
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=40 ; i++) {
            employees.add(new Employee("Employee "+i, 20+i));
            images.add(createImage(i));
        }       
    }

    public void initialize() {

        listView.getItems().setAll(employees);

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {

            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

            {
                setPrefHeight(100);
            }

            @Override
            public void updateIndex(int index) {
                super.updateIndex(index);
                if (index < 0 || index > employees.size()) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(employees.get(index).getName());
                    if (index >= 0 && index < images.size()) {
                        imageView.setImage(images.get(index));
                        setGraphic(imageView);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Image createImage(int i) {
        /// just a hack to get an image with a number in it
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
        label.setMinSize(100, 100);
        label.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        label.requestLayout();
        label.applyCss();
        new Scene(label);
        return label.snapshot(null, null);
    }


}
```

Note that all of these assume the lists are fixed for the duration of the display. If that is not the case, the easiest way to handle dynamic lists is with the first approach. Use `ObservableList`s for the objects and images, register listeners with them, and update the list view's items accordingly if they change.

For completeness, here is an application class, `Employee` class, and FXML file to test this. Any of these approaches work with these two files:

```
public class Employee {

    private final String name ;
    private final int age ;

    public Employee(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.age = age ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }


}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Employees.fxml")));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/14" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.listview.Controller">
    <center>
        <ListView fx:id="listView"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```